# Detect gray things with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to detect an object using OpenCV that is distinctly different from other elements in the scene as it's gray. This is good because I can just run a test with R == G == B and it allows to be independent of luminosity, but doing it pixel by pixel is slow.

Is there a faster way to detect gray things? Maybe there's an OpenCV method that does the R == G == B test... `cv2.inRange` does color thresholding, it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: What about splitting image I -> (A,B,C) and then checking [(A-B)+(A-C)]==0 ? (convert the images to signed format first). You'll avoid the  pixel-by-pixel thing.

Comment: Or; Split the image, use absdiff and threshold the image.

Comment: hmmm, if R==G==B then 2R-G-B=0. what about calculating 2R-G-B and then using countNonZero? Just a hunch though.

Comment: LOL @GilLevi I think my expression is equivalent but didn't realize i could have rewritten it. Yours look nicer :D

Comment: @GilLevi actually there's lots of other combinations that satisfy 2R-G-B=0, such as RGB(50,25,75) so that's not such a good idea ;-)

Comment: @Roger Rowland, your'e right! thanks for the comment

Comment: I'm quite suprised that R==G==B is slow. Post your code please

Comment: hmm, all of you (including remi's answer below) seem to assume, that the whole image is gray

Comment: Damn, @GilLevi you are right!! :D

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using that is too slow? Then we have a base line to test against.

Comment: @berak why is that? The image is 3 channels not gray. Another thing that I find surprising in this question is also the concrete application of finding, with this method, purely gray stuff. There are lots of cases where  R!=G!=B that still would appear greyish

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest method I can find in Python is to use slicing to compare each channel. After a few test runs, this method is upwards of 200 times faster than two nested for-loops.

```
bg = im[:,:,0] == im[:,:,1] # B == G
gr = im[:,:,1] == im[:,:,2] # G == R
slices = np.bitwise_and(bg, gr, dtype= np.uint8) * 255
```

This will generate a binary image where gray objects are indicated by white pixels. If you do not need a binary image, but only a logical array where grey pixels are indicated by `True` values, this method gets even faster:

```
slices = np.bitwise_and(bg, gr)
```

Omitting the type cast and multiplication yields a method 500 times faster than nested loops.

Running this operation on this test image:

[image: image with gray object]

Gives the following result:

[image: gray object detection mask]

As you can see, the gray object is correctly detected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that such a simple check is slow, probably you are not coding it efficiently.

Here is a short piece of code that should do that for you. It optimal neither in speed nor in memory, but quite in number of lines of code :)

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> planes;
cv::split(image, planes);
cv::Mat mask = planes[0] == planes[1];
mask &= planes[1] == planes[2];
```

For the sake of it, here is a comparison with something that would be the fastest way to do it in my opinion (without parallelization)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <sys/time.h> //gettimeofday

static
double
P_ellapsedTime(struct timeval t0, struct timeval t1)
{
  //return ellapsed time in seconds
  return (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1.0 + (t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000000.0;
}



int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


  struct timeval t0, t1;
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1]);
  assert(image.type() == CV_8UC3);
  std::vector<cv::Mat> planes;
  std::cout << "Image resolution=" << image.rows << "x" << image.cols << std::endl;
  gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
  cv::split(image, planes);
  cv::Mat mask = planes[0] == planes[1];
  mask &= planes[1] == planes[2];
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  std::cout << "Time using split: " << P_ellapsedTime(t0, t1) << "s" << std::endl;

  cv::Mat mask2 = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8U);
  unsigned char *imgBuf = image.data;
  unsigned char *maskBuf = mask2.data;
  gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
  for (; imgBuf != image.dataend; imgBuf += 3, maskBuf++)
    *maskBuf = (imgBuf[0] == imgBuf[1] && imgBuf[1] == imgBuf[2]) ? 255 : 0;
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  std::cout << "Time using loop: " << P_ellapsedTime(t0, t1) << "s" << std::endl;

  cv::namedWindow("orig", 0);
  cv::imshow("orig", image);
  cv::namedWindow("mask", 0);
  cv::imshow("mask", mask);
  cv::namedWindow("mask2", 0);
  cv::imshow("mask2", mask2);
  cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

Bench on an image:

```
Image resolution=3171x2179
Time using split: 0.06353s
Time using loop: 0.029044s
```